# List of supported kernels for KernelRidge estimator

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I'm using the `KernelRidge` estimator, which apparently supports various kernels. I've read the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.kernel_ridge.KernelRidge.html):

Apparently one can define own kernel functions. Somehow I have the impression, that there are some predefined kernels. Unfortunately, I can't them? Do you know if there are some? And if yes, could you point me to a location which describes them and their parameters?

Answer (score 6):

Following kernels are supported:  `RBF`, `laplacian`, `polynomial`, `exponential`, `chi2` and `sigmoid` kernels. I drew conclusion from observing the "gamma parameter" description of `KernelRidge` documentation.

The mathematical formulation of these kernels can be found at [this link](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/metrics.html#metrics) as mentioned earlier by @ndrizza.

I am also trying to figure out the string arguments for kernel, based on information from SVR page, I think they are something like `linear`, `poly`, `rbf`, and `sigmoid`. [SVR page](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html#sklearn.svm.SVR).

Answer (score 3):

I found a good resource.

Here is a list of some kernels:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.metrics.pairwise

Here are some further details about the kernels:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/metrics.html#metrics